# Ubuntu home folder

Tags: unity

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 & suddenly I am seeing extra files in home directory starting from .filename. I know these are the some of the system files & third party software files but in Ubuntu . extension files are hidden by default, how do I again make it hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

You can also set it to show or hide as default in nautilus preferences.

Comment: oh so thank you, it worked in less than a second, can i ask you for a little more help

Comment: Sure! What's up?

Comment: My ubuntu is not running as faster as it was when i installed it, is there any way i can improve its performance.

Comment: Have you installed lots of things? BTW, if my answer was right, please click the green tick below the down arrow! I used the following tutorial - http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/ It works on 14.04 not just 13.X

Comment: @user299731Even if Tim said "ok": If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.